# handling localized text in database

Tags: mysql, localization

[image]

I have one table **rewards** that has rewards info, each reward has some basic info such as count, id, title, message & description. To be able to localize we give ID`s to these text items.

I have another table **languages**, where we keep all text messages, along with key ID & language ID.

What I need is a query to get all rewards along with localized text from the table. For example, if I pass language as English (`lang_id` is 1 in language table), it should return all rewards with English text.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from
rewards, languages
where rewards.id = languages.key_id   
and languages.lang_id = 1;
```

P.S. when asking questions on stackoverflow, you should show at least some research effort - what you tried and what haven't worked. 
Probably, you do not realise, that if you want to retrieve information from two tables at once, you should use JOIN in sql.

Here is a link that might be helpful in your further research:

[MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Well, the question neither shows any research effort nor it is particularly useful. Rather than downvoting and not giving any answer, I gave a short and precise answer, since it really goes beyond my time limits to explain a concept of joins in this case.

Comment: That's true, and I guess it's a matter of opinion whether poor questions deserve good answers (there is the (Reversal Badge](/help/badges/95) available if you believe so!).  Anyway, as I said, thank you for this contribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am completely new to DB queries, I know only basic queries. Before posting the question here I did read & tried inner join & left inner join, I could not get what I wanted & hence I posted it here to hear from experts. I will keep in mind your suggestions for my future questions.